# openssl fips error

Tags: windows, visual-c++, 64-bit, openssl, fips

I use OpenSSL libraries in a service project running in Windows. These libraries are build as FIPS compliant. In a 32-bit Windows OS, the service works fine. However, the program crashes when I try to run the project in a 64-bit Windows (Windows Server 2008, Windows 7 etc.).

The output of the program:
.\fips\fips.c(146): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE

I am using C++ in order to implement that service project and working with MS Visual Studio 2010. Furthermore, I am building that project with Win32 settings and also use 32-bit compiled OpenSSL libraries as well in a 64-bit platform where I received that error. The OpenSSL version is 0.9.8r.

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks in advance.